# Form Displays Input Warning But Still Submits

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, validation

I have a form in which I want users to input data. However, I do not want users to insert certain words. The code I have added recognizes these words and a popup message appears. When the user acknowledges the message, the form submits the data regardless. I've no idea why this happens. The code is listed below.

HTML Form

```
<form name="form1" action="#" method="post" required>
    <label>Line 1:&nbsp; </label>
    <input type="text" name="firstline" required onClick="select_area()"><br/>
    <label>Line 2:&nbsp; </label>
    <input type="text" name="secondline" required onClick="select_area2()"><br/>
    <label>Line 3:&nbsp; </label>
    <input type="text" name="thirdline" required onClick="select_area3()"><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" id="submit" value="Submit" onClick="validate_text();">
    <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

JavaScript File

```
var swear_words_arr=new Array("word1","word2","word3");

var swear_alert_arr=new Array;
var swear_alert_count=0;
function reset_alert_count()
{
    swear_alert_count=0;
}
function validate_text()
{
    reset_alert_count();
    var compare_text=document.form1.firstline.value;
    for(var i=0; i<swear_words_arr.length; i++) {
        for(var j=0; j<(compare_text.length); j++) {
            if(swear_words_arr[i]==compare_text.substring(j,(j+swear_words_arr[i].length)).toLowerCase())
            {
                swear_alert_arr[swear_alert_count]=compare_text.substring(j,(j+swear_words_arr[i].length));
                swear_alert_count++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    var compare_text=document.form1.secondline.value;
    for(var i=0; i<swear_words_arr.length; i++) {
        for(var j=0; j<(compare_text.length); j++) {
            if(swear_words_arr[i]==compare_text.substring(j,(j+swear_words_arr[i].length)).toLowerCase())
            {
                swear_alert_arr[swear_alert_count]=compare_text.substring(j,(j+swear_words_arr[i].length));
                swear_alert_count++;
            }
        }
    }   
    
    var compare_text=document.form1.thirdline.value;
    for(var i=0; i<swear_words_arr.length; i++) {
        for(var j=0; j<(compare_text.length); j++) {
            if(swear_words_arr[i]==compare_text.substring(j,(j+swear_words_arr[i].length)).toLowerCase())
            {
                swear_alert_arr[swear_alert_count]=compare_text.substring(j,(j+swear_words_arr[i].length));
                swear_alert_count++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    var alert_text="";
    for(var k=1; k<=swear_alert_count; k++){
        alert_text+="\n" + "(" + k + ")  " + swear_alert_arr[k-1];
    }
    if(swear_alert_count>0) {
        alert("The message will not be sent!!!\nThe following illegal words were found:\n_______________________________\n" + alert_text + "\n_______________________________");
        document.form1.text.select();
    } else {
        document.form1.submit();
    }
}

function select_area()
{
    document.form1.firstline.select();
}
    
function select_area2()
{
    document.form1.secondline.select();
}
    
function select_area3()
{
    document.form1.thirdline.select();
}
    
window.onload=reset_alert_count;
```

Comment: You dont appear to actually remove the offending words, you only tell people you found them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no part in your function that blocks the action of the form.

For example, like 'return false' or 'preventdefault'.

You can use onClick, but onsubmit is recommended so that you can use the function to submit via keyboard.

```js
var swear_words_arr = new Array("word1", "word2", "word3");

var swear_alert_arr = new Array;
var swear_alert_count = 0;

function reset_alert_count() {
    swear_alert_count = 0;
}

function validate_text() {
    reset_alert_count();

    var compare_text = document.form1.firstline.value;
    for (var i = 0; i < swear_words_arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < (compare_text.length); j++) {
            if (swear_words_arr[i] == compare_text.substring(j, (j + swear_words_arr[i].length)).toLowerCase()) {
                swear_alert_arr[swear_alert_count] = compare_text.substring(j, (j + swear_words_arr[i].length));
                swear_alert_count++;
            }
        }
    }

    var compare_text = document.form1.secondline.value;
    for (var i = 0; i < swear_words_arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < (compare_text.length); j++) {
            if (swear_words_arr[i] == compare_text.substring(j, (j + swear_words_arr[i].length)).toLowerCase()) {
                swear_alert_arr[swear_alert_count] = compare_text.substring(j, (j + swear_words_arr[i].length));
                swear_alert_count++;
            }
        }
    }

    var compare_text = document.form1.thirdline.value;
    for (var i = 0; i < swear_words_arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < (compare_text.length); j++) {
            if (swear_words_arr[i] == compare_text.substring(j, (j + swear_words_arr[i].length)).toLowerCase()) {
                swear_alert_arr[swear_alert_count] = compare_text.substring(j, (j + swear_words_arr[i].length));
                swear_alert_count++;
            }
        }
    }

    var alert_text = "";
    for (var k = 1; k <= swear_alert_count; k++) {
        alert_text += "\n" + "(" + k + ")  " + swear_alert_arr[k - 1];
    }

    if (swear_alert_count > 0) {
        alert("The message will not be sent!!!\nThe following illegal words were found:\n_______________________________\n" + alert_text + "\n_______________________________");
        return false;
        //document.form1.text.select(); <- This is incorrect syntax.
    }
}

function select_area() {
    document.form1.firstline.select();
}

function select_area2() {
    document.form1.secondline.select();
}

function select_area3() {
    document.form1.thirdline.select();
}

window.onload = reset_alert_count;
```

```html
<form name="form1" action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_text();">
    <label>Line 1:&nbsp; </label>
    <input type="text" name="firstline" required onClick="select_area()"><br />
    <label>Line 2:&nbsp; </label>
    <input type="text" name="secondline" required onClick="select_area2()"><br />
    <label>Line 3:&nbsp; </label>
    <input type="text" name="thirdline" required onClick="select_area3()"><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" id="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```